# Format to significant decimal places in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, number-formatting

How can I display numbers to *significant* decimal places in SQL Server?

Given that `MYFIELD` is of data type `NUMERIC(38,10)`:

Present result:

```
Select MYFIELD from MYTABLE:
1000.0000000000
1234.5600000000
2000.0000000000
```

Better result (half way there):

```
Select cast(MYFIELD as NUMERIC(38,2)) from MYTABLE:
1000.00
1234.56
2000.00
```

Desired result:

```
Select ??? from MYTABLE:
1000
1234.56
2000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to limit this to 2 decimal places or should this be valid from 0-10 decimal places?

Comment: My data is money-related and only contains up to 2 decimal places. But if those decimals are ".00" I would like to not display the decimals at all.

Comment: Might I ask, if this has to happen on the database? In my humble oppinion, this is a presentation layer issue and very well could be addressed at the client.

Comment: Serv - I would agree, however in this case I am fixing up a "batch script" which outputs directly from the SQL to a text file (csv), and so I am looking for a quick option :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to perform formatting-related tasks on the client side, for a multitude of reasons. However, starting from SQL Server 2012, you can do this:

```
select MyField, format(MyField, '0.##') as [MyFieldFormatted]
from dbo.MyTable;
```